# Inserting records not working on detailsview in insert mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, insert, detailsview

I have a detailsview that has multiple fields and is always only used in insert mode.  The problem I have been having is when I enter all the values into my detailsview and hit the insert button nothing happens.  Well the screen is refreshed but no new records are inserted to the table.

here is my aspx code:

```
            <td class="style2" colspan="2">
                <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" DataKeyNames="requestid"
                Height="29px" Width="928px" AutoGenerateRows="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"
                GridLines="None" Style="margin-right: 0px; text-align: left; margin-top: 0px;" 
                    ondatabound="DetailsView1_DataBound" 
                    onitemcommand="DetailsView1_ItemCommand" 
                    oniteminserting="DetailsView1_ItemInserting" >
                <Fields>
                    <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Request ID" HeaderText="Leave Request ID" Visible="False">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label19" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("requestid") %>'></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox165" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("requestid") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("requestid") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Employee ID" HeaderText="Employee ID" >
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label21" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("emppid") %>'></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox17" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("emppid") %>' 
                               ></asp:TextBox>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("emppid") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Approver ID" HeaderText="Approver ID">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" style="text-transform:uppercase;" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceApprover"
                                DataTextField="APPROVNAME" DataValueField="APPROVERID" 
                                SelectedValue='<%# Bind("approverid") %>'>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("approverid") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Leave Type" SortExpression="reqleavecode">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList6" runat="server" Height="20px"
                                onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList6_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="171px" 
                                ondatabound="DropDownList6_DataBound" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                SelectedIndex='<%# bind("reqleavecode") %>'>
                                <asp:ListItem  Text="-- SELECT LEAVE --" Value ="-1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="1E">EDUCATION LEAVE</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="1X">EXCUSED LEAVE</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="1F">FUNERAL LEAVE</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="1J">JURY DUTY</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="1N">ON THE JOB INJURY LEAVE</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="1P">PERSONAL HOLIDAY</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="4 ">SICK LEAVE</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="3">VACATION</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="Label26" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("reqleavecode") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("reqleavecode") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Leave Type" HeaderText="Leave Reason" 
                        Visible="False">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("leavetype") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
                                AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="REASON" 
                                DataValueField="REASON" Height="19px" 
                                onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList5_SelectedIndexChanged1" 
                                SelectedValue='<%# Bind("leavetype") %>' Width="163px">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1Reason" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="DropDownList5" ErrorMessage="*Leave Reason Required" 
                                ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="start date" HeaderText="Leave Date">
                        <EditItemTemplate>     
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("lstdate",  "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>' Height="21px"
                                Width="67px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox5_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True"
                                TargetControlID="TextBox5">
                            </asp:CalendarExtender>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="TextBox5" ErrorMessage="*Leave Date Required" 
                                ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <br />
                            <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator18" runat="server" 
                                ControlToCompare="TextBox7" ControlToValidate="TextBox5" 
                                ErrorMessage="Leave date cannot be after start date" ForeColor="Red" 
                                Operator="LessThanEqual" ToolTip="Must choose start date before end date"></asp:CompareValidator>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lenddate") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="lenddate" HeaderText="Return Date">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("lenddate",  "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>' Height="21px"
                                Width="67px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox7_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox7">
                            </asp:CalendarExtender>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="TextBox7" ErrorMessage="*Return Date Required" 
                                ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <br />
                            <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" 
                                ControlToCompare="TextBox5" ControlToValidate="TextBox7" 
                                ErrorMessage="Return date cannot be before start date" ForeColor="Red" 
                                Operator="GreaterThanEqual"></asp:CompareValidator>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lsttime") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Leave Time" HeaderText="Leave Time">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox15" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lsttime") %>' Width="85px"
                                Height="22px" ToolTip="Type 'A' or 'P' to switch AM/PM"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="TextBox15_MaskedEditExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox15"
                                Mask="99:99" MaskType="Time" AcceptAMPM="True" ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" 
                                CultureAMPMPlaceholder="" CultureCurrencySymbolPlaceholder="" 
                                CultureDateFormat="" CultureDatePlaceholder="" CultureDecimalPlaceholder="" 
                                CultureThousandsPlaceholder="" CultureTimePlaceholder="" Enabled="True" />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="TextBox15" ErrorMessage="*Invalid Time" ForeColor="Red" 
                                ValidationExpression="^((([0]?[1-9]|1[0-2])(:|\.)[0-5][0-9]((:|\.)[0-5][0-9])?( )?(AM|am|aM|Am|PM|pm|pM|Pm))|(([0]?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(:|\.)[0-5][0-9]((:|\.)[0-5][0-9])?))$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lendtime") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Return Time" HeaderText="Return Time">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lsttime") %>' Width="85px"
                                Height="22px" ToolTip="Type 'A' or 'P' to switch AM/PM"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="TextBox8_MaskedEditExtender" runat="server" 
                                AcceptAMPM="True" CultureAMPMPlaceholder="" CultureCurrencySymbolPlaceholder="" 
                                CultureDateFormat="" CultureDatePlaceholder="" CultureDecimalPlaceholder="" 
                                CultureThousandsPlaceholder="" CultureTimePlaceholder="" Enabled="True" 
                                ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" Mask="99:99" MaskType="Time" 
                                TargetControlID="TextBox8" />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator10" 
                                runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox8" ErrorMessage="*Invalid Time" 
                                ForeColor="Red" 
                                ValidationExpression="^((([0]?[1-9]|1[0-2])(:|\.)[0-5][0-9]((:|\.)[0-5][0-9])?( )?(AM|am|aM|Am|PM|pm|pM|Pm))|(([0]?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(:|\.)[0-5][0-9]((:|\.)[0-5][0-9])?))$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("standby") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Standby" HeaderText="On Standby">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource10"
                                DataTextField="&quot;Y/N&quot;" DataValueField="&quot;Y/N&quot;" SelectedValue='<%# BIND("standby") %>'>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("rsndecline") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Reason Decline" 
                        HeaderText="Request Decline Reason" InsertVisible="False">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("rsndecline") %>' 
                                Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("status") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Status" HeaderText="Request Status" InsertVisible="False">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox13" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("status") %>' Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("empremarks") %>' 
                                ToolTip="Additional information pertaining to leave request"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="empremarks" HeaderText="Leave Request Remarks">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox14" runat="server" style="text-transform:uppercase;" Text='<%# Bind("empremarks") %>' 
                                TextMode="MultiLine" Height="47px" Width="452px" 
                                ToolTip="Additional information pertaining to leave request."></asp:TextBox>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                CommandName="Edit" Height="21px" Text="Edit" Width="65px" />
                            &nbsp; &nbsp;
                            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                CommandName="New" Height="21px" Text="New" Width="65px" />
                            &nbsp; &nbsp;
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" 
                                Text="Submit Request" />
                            &nbsp;
                            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                CommandName="Cancel" Height="21px" onclick="Button2_Click1" Text="Cancel" />
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lstdate") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Fields>
                        </asp:DetailsView>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style2" colspan="2">
                        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Height="21px"  onclick="Button3_Click" 
                            Text="With Pay Leave Request" />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Height="21px"  onclick="Button4_Click" 
                            Text="Without Pay Leave Request" style="margin-left: 13px" Width="221px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringEvent %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringEvent.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT REASON, LEAVECODE FROM LEAVRSN">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="LEAVECODE" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQLLEAVECODE" runat="server" 
       ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringEvent %>" 
       ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringEvent.ProviderName %>"                
       SelectCommand="SELECT LEAVETYPE, LEAVECODE FROM LVTYPE ORDER BY LEAVECODE">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceApprover" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringEvent %>"
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringEvent.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT APPROVERID, APPROVNAME FROM APPROVER ORDER BY APPROVERID">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource10" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringEvent %>"
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringEvent.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM YNSELECT ORDER BY ALPH"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1111" runat="server">

    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" ForeColor="#999999" 
                Text="Exhibit B PP-8"></asp:Label>
            <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" DeleteMethod="DeleteRequestForm"
                InsertMethod="InsertRequestForm" SelectMethod="SelectRequestEMPID" TypeName="DataHandler.DataHandler"  
                UpdateMethod="UpdateRequestFormLastName" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="requestid" Type="Int64" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="requestid" Type="Int64" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="emppid" Type="Decimal" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="leavetype" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="lstdate" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="lenddate" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="lsttime" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="lendtime" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="standby" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="status" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="rsndecline" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="empremarks" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="approverid" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="reqleavecode" Type="Int32" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <SelectParameters>
                   <%-- <asp:Parameter Name="emppid" Type="Decimal" />--%>
                   <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="emppid" QueryStringField="emppid" Type="Decimal" />
                </SelectParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="requestid" Type="Int64" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="emppid" Type="Decimal" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="leavetype" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="lstdate" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="lenddate" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="lsttime" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="lendtime" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="requesreason" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="standby" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="status" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="rsndecline" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="empremarks" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="approverid" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="LASTNAME" Type="String" />
                </UpdateParameters>
            </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource2" runat="server" 
                            SelectMethod="SelectNameEmployeeForm" 
                            TypeName="DataHandler.DataHandler">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:Parameter Name="empid" Type="Decimal" />
                                <asp:Parameter Name="firstname" Type="String" />
                                <asp:Parameter Name="lastname" Type="String" />
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
            <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <asp:Label ID="Label27" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
</asp:Content>
```

my code behind:

```
    public partial class newRequestForm : System.Web.UI.Page
       {
         public string lvtype;
         public string lvrequest;
       private DataSet GetData()
       {
         ConnectionStringSettingsCollection cssc = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;
         var sql = "SELECT LEAVETYPE, LEAVECODE FROM TESTBWTIME.BWLVTYPE ORDER BY LEAVECODE";

           using (iDB2Connection conn = new iDB2Connection(GetConnectionString()))
           {
             conn.Open();
             using (iDB2Command cmd = new iDB2Command(sql, conn))
             {
                cmd.DeriveParameters();
                using (iDB2DataAdapter da = new iDB2DataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                   da.Fill(ds);
                   return ds;
                }
             }
          }
        }

   private String GetConnectionString()
   {
      ConnectionStringSettingsCollection cssc = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;
      return cssc["connStringNET"].ToString();
   }
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {    
      if (!IsPostBack)
      {
        DetailsView1.DataBind();
      }
   }

   protected void DetailsView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     TextBox employeeID = (TextBox)(DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox17"));
     DropDownList approverID = (DropDownList)(DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList4"));
       if (DetailsView1.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Insert)
       {
         var CurrUser = "";

         Account.Login uusr = new Account.Login();
         CurrUser = uusr.User.Identity.Name.ToString().ToUpper();
         employeeID.Text = CurrUser.Substring(3, 3);
         string supusrid = "";
         DataHandler.DataHandler Dt = new DataHandler.DataHandler();
         supusrid = Dt.SelectRequestApproverForm(supusrid);
         approverID.SelectedValue = supusrid;
      }
   }

   protected void DropDownList6_DataBound1(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     DropDownList lvreason = (DropDownList)(DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList5"));
     DropDownList lvtype = (DropDownList)(DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList6"));
     string selectedValue = lvtype.SelectedValue.ToString().ToUpper();
     if (selectedValue == "4 " || selectedValue == "1F")
       {
          SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["LEAVECODE"].DefaultValue = selectedValue;
          DetailsView1.Fields[4].Visible = true;
          lvreason.Visible = true;
       }
    else
       {
        DetailsView1.Fields[4].Visible = false;
       }
  }
  protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
  {
     DropDownList lvtype = (DropDownList)(DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList6"));
     DropDownList lvreason = (DropDownList)(DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList5"));

     if (lvtype.SelectedValue != "")
     {
      if (lvtype.SelectedValue == "3 ")
      {
      lvreason.Text.Equals("VACATION").ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
      lvtype.Text.Equals("VACATION").ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
      }
      else if (lvtype.SelectedValue == "1E")
      {
      lvreason.Text.Equals("EDUCATION LEAVE").ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
      lvtype.Text.Equals("EDUCATION LEAVE").ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
      }
      else if (lvtype.SelectedValue == "1N")
      {
      lvreason.Text.Equals("ON THE JOB INJURY LEAVE").ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
      lvtype.Text.Equals("ON THE JOB INJURY LEAVE").ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
      }
      else if (lvtype.SelectedValue == "1J")
      {
      lvreason.Text.Equals("JURY DUTY").ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
      lvtype.Text.Equals("JURY DUTY").ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
      }
      else if (lvtype.SelectedValue == "1X")
      {
      lvreason.Text.Equals("EXCUSED LEAVE").ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
      lvtype.Text.Equals("EXCUSED LEAVE").ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
      }
      else if (lvtype.SelectedValue == "1P")
      {
      lvreason.Text.Equals("PERSONAL HOLIDAY").ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
      lvtype.Text.Equals("PERSONAL HOLIDAY").ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
      }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Could try adding DefaultMode="Insert" to your DetailsView? Also, you have OnItemCommand hooked up but there's no definition for DetailsView1_OnItemCommand in your code-behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in order to bind after add data

```
void DetailsView1_ItemInserted(object sender, 
    DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs e)
  {
    // Refresh the GridView control after a new record is inserted 
    // in the DetailsView control.
    DetailsView1.DataBind();
  }
```

And add this to your control `OnItemInserted="DetailsView1_ItemInserted"`

Comment: When I added databind in there was no change to the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing Details `DetailsView1.DataBind();` in the `DetailsView1_ItemInserting` after adding the records call the `DetailsView1.DataBind();` method.

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
           // do your work 
          // .........
          //...... 
    DetailsView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: When I added databind in there was no change to the behavior of the insert.

Comment: @user1596472 before calling `DetailsView1.DataBind` also call the `ObjectDataSource1.DataBind()` method. Check it.

Comment: thank you for your reply.  unfortunately my record is still not inserting.